# Proving the shortest function connecting two points is a straight line WITHOUT assuming the Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: optimization, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

For learning purposes, I'm trying to prove that the shortest function passing through the two points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$ is a straight line, without using the Euler-Lagrange equation.

My attempt at a proof is below. I think I have most of it, but I get stuck at the end.
How do I finish the proof?

---

#### My attempt:

Assume $y$ is the function of $x$ to be determined, which satisfies $y(x_1) = y_1$ and $y(x_2) = y_2$.
I define the length to be minimized as follows:

$$L(y) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \,dx$$

Consider perturbing $y$ by some multiple $\delta$ of an arbitrary deviation $w$ that vanishes at $x_1$ and $x_2$:

$$L(y, \delta) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{d(y + \delta w)}{dx}\right)^2} \,dx$$

$$L(y, \delta) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx} + \delta\frac{dw}{dx}\right)^2} \,dx$$

If $y$ minimizes $L$, then for any fixed $w$ the rate of change (i.e., derivative) of $L$ with respect to $\delta$ must approach zero as $\delta \to 0$:

$$
\frac{d}{d\delta}L(y, \delta)
= \frac{d}{d\delta}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx} + \delta\frac{dw}{dx}\right)^2} \,dx  \\
= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{d}{d\delta} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx} + \delta\frac{dw}{dx}\right)^2} \,dx  \\
= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\left(\frac{dy}{dx} + \delta\frac{dw}{dx}\right) \frac{dw}{dx}}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx} + \delta\frac{dw}{dx}\right)^2}} \,dx \to 0
$$

Specifically, since this holds true when $\delta = 0$, we have:

$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dw}{dx}}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}} \,dx = 0
$$

#### Now here's where I get stuck:

I need to get rid of $w$ somehow.

Because the equality above needs to hold for *all* $w$, I think I would prefer to *pick* $w$ to be something convenient that makes my life easier; say, $\frac{dw}{dx} = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$, to cancel the denominator.
But I **cannot** assume this is possible, as $w$ must satisfy **two** boundary conditions:
it must vanish at *both* $x_1$ *and* at $x_2$.

#### How am I supposed to proceed?

Comment: The ugly square root in the denominator seems to originate from your choice of parameterizing the curve by the $x$ coordinate. If, wlog, you parameterize it by arc length instead, I think a lot of grief would be saved.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: That doesn't solve the problem I'm asking about though. Even if that wasn't there I would still need to get rid of $w$ somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, two final steps might be following.

First, you integrate last expression by parts:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{y'w'}{\sqrt{1+ (y')^2}} dx 
= \left \lbrack  \frac{y'w}{\sqrt{1+ (y')^2}} \right \rbrack \Bigg \vert_{x_1}^{x_2} -  \int_{x_1}^{x_2} w \frac{y''}{{(1+ (y')^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}} dx $$

Since $w(x)$ vanishes at the endpoints, then we have

$$ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} w \frac{y''}{{(1+ (y')^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}} dx \equiv 0 $$
for any choice of $w$.

The second step is following. Now consider family of functions $w_{x_0, n}(x)$
($x_0$ is a point from $(x_1, x_2)$ and $n$ belongs to a subset of natural numbers s.t. $(x_0 - \frac{1}{n}, x_0 + \frac{1}{n}) \subset (x_1, x_2)$ ):

- $w_{x_0, n}(x_1) = w_{x_0, n}(x_2) = 0 $
- $w_{x_0, n}(x)$ is zero outside $(x_0 - \frac{1}{n}, x_0 + \frac{1}{n})$
- $w_{x_0, n}(x)$ is positive on $( x_0 - \frac{1}{n}, x_0 + \frac{1}{n} )$

It's easy to show that

$$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow + \infty} \int_{x_1}^{x_2} w_{x_0, n} \frac{y''}{{(1+ (y')^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}} dx = \frac{ y''(x_0)}{{(1+ (y'(x_0))^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}.  $$

But we know that each of these integrals is equal to 0, so $y''(x_0) \equiv 0$ for $x_0 \in (x_1, x_2) $. By continuity you just obtain that $y'' \equiv 0$ at $\lbrack x_1, x_2 \rbrack$ and thus it's a linear function of $x$.

Comment: I'm confused what $n$ is doing in your definition, it doesn't seem to be present in the definition anywhere.

Comment: Just for a sake of simplicity imagine that $w_{x_0, n}$ is a function which is positive only on $(x_0 - \frac{1}{n}, x_0 + \frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Oh so you're basically saying it's a Dirac delta centered at $x_0$?

Comment: It's limit is a Dirac delta, yes :)

Comment: Sorry, I was quite inaccurate in some phrases. Now I think that I've cleared it up.

Comment: I like the answer, I can't help but wonder if there's a simpler way to do it than requiring integration by parts though!

Comment: Also, how did you differentiate $\frac{y'}{\sqrt{(1+ (y')^2)}}$ to get $\frac{y''}{{(1+ (y')^2)}^{3/2}}$? Aren't you [missing some terms there](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5By+%2F+Sqrt%5B1+%2B+y%5E2%5D%2C+x%2C+NonConstants+-%3E+%7By%7D%5D)?

Comment: I think nothing has been lost: 
$$ \left ( \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+{(y^{'})}^2}} \right )^{'} = \frac{y''\cdot \sqrt{1+{y^\prime}^2}-y^\prime \cdot \frac{2\cdot y^\prime \cdot y''}{2\sqrt{1+{y^\prime}^2}}}{1+{(y^{\prime})}^2} = y'' \cdot \frac{1+(y')^2 - (y')^2}{\left (1+(y')^2 \right )^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$. In my opinion, the most non-trivial part of reasoning is the way to pick $w(x)$, not integrating by parts :)

Comment: Oh wow you multiplied it out and simplified it massively haha. Yeah I agree, I think choosing $w$ is harder, especially for more complicated examples. Thanks!

Comment: You know, the way of choosing $w(x)$ in such kind of variational equations is somewhat universal: I believe that this detail is present in many proofs of Euler-Lagrange conditions.

Answer (score 1):

One can change the point of view a bit, you have

$$(*) \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{y'w'}{\sqrt{1+ (y')^2}} dx = 0$$

for all $w$ so that $w(x_1) = w(x_2) = 0$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} w'(x) dx = w(x_2) - w(x_1) = 0-0= 0.$$

On the other hand, if $u$ satisfies $\int udx = 0$, then

$$w(x) = \int_{x_1}^x u(s) ds $$

will have $w(x_1) = w(x_2) = 0$. So (*) is the same as

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g(x) u(x) dx = 0$$

for all $u$ so that $\int udx= 0$, and $g = \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+ (y')^2}}$. Note that this would imply

$$ g(x) = \frac{y'(x)}{\sqrt{1+ (y')^2}} = C$$

for some constant $C$. Then

$$y'(x) = \sqrt{\frac{C}{1-C}}$$

is also constant. Thus $y(x)$ is a linear map.

Comment: When you say "if $u$ satisfies $\int u\,dx = 0$" do you mean "if $u$ satisfies $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} u\,dx = 0$"?

Comment: Ok thanks just checking.

Comment: How did you get the last implication (that $g(x)$ is constant)? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: Actually, just kidding, I just realized that's the [fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations). However, am I missing something or does that lemma imply $C = 0 \implies y'(x) = 0 \implies y(x) = C_0$?

Comment: I am looking for the proof that $g$ is constant. One can show that by (equality case of ) Cauchy Schwarz, but I remembered I saw an easier proof.

Comment: Hm okay that's fine, I'm not too worried about that. What I'm worried about more is, doesn't the fundamental lemma imply $C = 0$?

Comment: Your original equation (*) is not quite satisfies the assumption of the fundamental lemma. @Mehrdad

Comment: Oh, interesting! Which assumption does it break...?

Comment: In that lemma, there's $h$ in the integral, but now there is $h'$. @Mehrdad

Comment: Oh, it's the difference between $w(x_1) = 0$ and $w'(x_1) = 0$, I see now!

Comment: PLease let me know if you still have questions, but I need to sleep now. I will reply it tomorrow. Cheers! @Mehrdad

Comment: Could you explain how you used Cauchy-Schwarz to prove what you mentioned?